# The difference between pointer address

Tags: c, pointers, memory-address

I am a Java programmer and recently play with C for fun. Now I am learning address and pointers which are a little bit confusing for me. Here is my question. See the below two blocks of the code.

```
void withinArray(int * a, int size, int * ptr) {
    int x;
    printf("ptr is %d\n", ptr);
    printf("a is %d\n", a);
    printf("difference in pointers is: %d\n", ptr - a);
    x = ptr - intArray;
    printf("x is %d\n", x);
}

void doubleSize() {
  double doubArray[10];
  double * doubPtr1;
  double * doubPtr2;

  doubPtr1 = doubArray;
  doubPtr2= doubArray+1;
  int p2 = doubPtr2;
  int p1 = doubPtr1;

  printf("p2-p1 is %d\n", p2-p1);
  printf("doubPtr2-doubPtr1 is %d\n", doubPtr2-doubPtr1);
}

int main(void)
{
  int a[10];
  int *intarray = a;
  int *p = intarray + 9;

  printf(withinArray(a, 10, p));
  return 0;
}
```

I am wondering for function `withinArray()`, why we could directly get the `x` value, which is 9? But for the other method, we have to convert `doubPtr` to `int` first and then we can get the difference between pointers in `int`?

From my understanding, in `doubleSize()`, `doubPtr2-doubPtr1 = 1` means the difference in pointer address in memory is `1`. But why the `withinArray()` doesn't need to do so?

Comment: What is `intArray` in `withinArray`?

Comment: Also, `printf("%d\n",  withinArray(a, 10, p));` is incorrect since `withinArray()` returns `void`. Furthermore, the type of the result of pointer subtraction is `ptrdiff_t` which is to be printed using `%td`.

Comment: @haccks Sorry for typo, the intArray should be a here.

Answer (score 3):

A difference of 1 between two pointers means that the pointers point to adjacent units of memory of the *size of the objects pointed at*.

Thus, given:

```
int i[2];
int *ip0 = &i[0];
int *ip1 = &i[1];
double d[2];
double *dp0 = &d[0];
double *dp1 = &d[1];
```

we could safely write:

```
assert((ip1 - ip0) == (dp1 - dp0));
assert(ip1 - ip0 == 1);
assert(dp1 - dp0 == 1);
```

However, you could also safely write:

```
assert((char *)ip1 - (char *)ip0 == sizeof(int));
assert((char *)dp1 - (char *)dp0 == sizeof(double));
```

and usually you would find that it is safe to write:

```
assert(sizeof(double) != sizeof(int));
```

though that is not guaranteed by the standard.

Also, as [Filipe Gonçalves](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2793118/filipe-goncalves) correctly points out in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19347166/the-difference-between-pointer-address/19347340#comment28664619_19347340), the difference between two pointers is formally only defined if the pointers are of the same type and point to two elements of the same array, or point to one element beyond the end of the array.  Note that standard C demands that given:

```
int a[100];
```

it is safe to generate the address `int *ip = &array[100];`, even though it is not safe to either read from or write to the location pointed at by `ip`.  The value stored in `ip` can be used in comparisons.

You also formally cannot subtract two `void *` values because there is no size for the type `void` (which is why my example used casts to `char *`, not `void *`).  Beware: GCC will not object to the subtraction of two `void *` values unless you include `-pedantic` in the options.

---

> Do you know why the value of `doubPtr2 - doubPtr1` (in my second method) is different from `x = ptr - a` (in my first method)?

Assuming that `intArray` is meant to be `a`, then this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static void withinArray(int *a, int *ptr)
{
    int x;
    printf("ptr is %p\n", (void *)ptr);
    printf("a   is %p\n", (void *)a);
    printf("difference in pointers is: %td\n", ptr - a);
    x = ptr - a;
    printf("x is %d\n", x);
}

static void doubleSize(void)
{
    double doubArray[10];
    double *doubPtr1 = doubArray;
    double *doubPtr2 = doubArray+1;
    int p2 = doubPtr2;
    int p1 = doubPtr1;

    printf("p1 = 0x%.8X\n", p1);
    printf("p2 = 0x%.8X\n", p2);
    printf("p2-p1 is %d\n", p2-p1);
    printf("doubPtr1 = %p\n", (void *)doubPtr1);
    printf("doubPtr1 = %p\n", (void *)doubPtr2);
    printf("doubPtr2-doubPtr1 is %td\n", doubPtr2-doubPtr1);
}

int main(void)
{
    int a[10];
    int *intarray = a;
    int *p = intarray + 9;

    withinArray(a, p);
    doubleSize();
    return 0;
}
```

compiles with warnings that I would ordinarily fix (change the type of `p1` and `p2` to `uintptr_t`, include `<inttypes.h>`, and format using `"p1 = 0x%.8" PRIXPTR "\n"` as the format string), and it generates the output:

```
ptr is 0x7fff5c5684a4
a   is 0x7fff5c568480
difference in pointers is: 9
x is 9
p1 = 0x5C5684B0
p2 = 0x5C5684B8
p2-p1 is 8
doubPtr1 = 0x7fff5c5684b0
doubPtr1 = 0x7fff5c5684b8
doubPtr2-doubPtr1 is 1
```

Fixed code generates:

```
ptr is 0x7fff5594f4a4
a   is 0x7fff5594f480
difference in pointers is: 9
x is 9
p1 = 0x7FFF5594F4B0
p2 = 0x7FFF5594F4B8
p2-p1 is 8
doubPtr1 = 0x7fff5594f4b0
doubPtr1 = 0x7fff5594f4b8
doubPtr2-doubPtr1 is 1
```

(The difference is in the number of hex digits printed for `p1` and `p2`.)

I assume that your puzzlement is about why the `int` code prints 9 rather than, say, 36, whereas the `double` code prints 8 instead of 1.

The answer is that when you subtract two pointers, the result is given in units of the *size of the objects pointed at* (which I seem to remember saying in my opening sentence).

When you execute `doubPtr2-doubPtr1`, the distance returned is in units of the number of `double` values between the two addresses.

However, the conversion to integer loses the type information, so you effectively have the `char *` (or `void *`) addresses of the two pointers in the integer, and the byte addresses are indeed 8 apart.

If we make two symmetrical routines, the information is clearer:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

static void intSize(void)
{
    int intArray[10];
    int *intPtr1 = intArray;
    int *intPtr2 = intArray+1;
    uintptr_t p2 = (uintptr_t)intPtr2;
    uintptr_t p1 = (uintptr_t)intPtr1;

    printf("p1 = 0x%.8" PRIXPTR "\n", p1);
    printf("p2 = 0x%.8" PRIXPTR "\n", p2);
    printf("p2-p1 is %" PRIdPTR "\n", p2-p1);
    printf("intPtr1 = %p\n", (void *)intPtr1);
    printf("intPtr1 = %p\n", (void *)intPtr2);
    printf("intPtr2-intPtr1 is %td\n", intPtr2-intPtr1);
}

static void doubleSize(void)
{
    double doubArray[10];
    double *doubPtr1 = doubArray;
    double *doubPtr2 = doubArray+1;
    uintptr_t p2 = (uintptr_t)doubPtr2;
    uintptr_t p1 = (uintptr_t)doubPtr1;

    printf("p1 = 0x%.8" PRIXPTR "\n", p1);
    printf("p2 = 0x%.8" PRIXPTR "\n", p2);
    printf("p2-p1 is %" PRIdPTR "\n", p2-p1);
    printf("doubPtr1 = %p\n", (void *)doubPtr1);
    printf("doubPtr1 = %p\n", (void *)doubPtr2);
    printf("doubPtr2-doubPtr1 is %td\n", doubPtr2-doubPtr1);
}

int main(void)
{
    doubleSize();
    intSize();
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
p1 = 0x7FFF5C93D4B0
p2 = 0x7FFF5C93D4B8
p2-p1 is 8
doubPtr1 = 0x7fff5c93d4b0
doubPtr1 = 0x7fff5c93d4b8
doubPtr2-doubPtr1 is 1
p1 = 0x7FFF5C93D4B0
p2 = 0x7FFF5C93D4B4
p2-p1 is 4
intPtr1 = 0x7fff5c93d4b0
intPtr1 = 0x7fff5c93d4b4
intPtr2-intPtr1 is 1
```

Remember Polya's advice in [How to Solve It](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/How_to_Solve_It):

- [Try to treat symmetrically what is symmetrical and do not destroy wantonly any natural symmetry.](http://books.google.com/books?id=X3xsgXjTGgoC&pg=PA200&lpg=PA200&dq=polya+%27wantonly+destroy+symmetry%27&source=bl&ots=t5Rr1HpHqe&sig=kbM_p-k_Hgs5udb5hevOvDNZF-c&hl=en&sa=X&ei=5RlbUsKrI4u4yAGP74CYBw&ved=0CDcQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=polya%20%27wantonly%20destroy%20symmetry%27&f=false)

Comment: Nice answer. Just adding some info for the OP, since he's new to C: pointer arithmetic should be performed only between pointers to elements in the same array (or 1 past the end). The difference between two pointers is of type ptrdiff_t (defined in stddef.h)

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves; True. The effect of subtracting one pointer from another is **undefined** unless both points to the element of the *same array*.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know that pointer arithmetic should only be performed btw pointers in the same array... A quick follow-up here, do you know why the value of doubPtr2-doubPtr1(in my second method) is different from x = ptr - intArray(in my first method)? Thanks!

Comment: I've come up with my best guess as to what you mean…see if that helps.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Your answer is so clear and well-organized. I appreciate your efforts for helping me out. Thanks!